# How can I do a generated image on a website?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to figure out how to make a website image, just some little blob of color without actually creating an image and putting an image tag and all of that.  Is it possible? 
Would I be drawing it with CSS, Javascript, or HTML5? If drawing it on the fly with something like Javascript, is that something that is a good idea? drawing over and over? 
Not sure where to start looking? Thanks for any help.

Here is an example of an image I'd like to make:  https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/0P1OxQU6AoPT5LnWG3jROJgEmdWoPKUw/image.png

Comment: Did you have a look at html5 Canvas? That might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

SVG is a good choice.  It allows you to use a document structure, much like that of HTML, for vector graphics.  The `<rect>` element makes a rectangle.  For more complex shapes like your example, check out paths.  More info here:  [Rounded corner only on one side of svg <rect>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34923888/362536)

Vector graphics are easy to generate and manipulate programatically.  They can also be sized and scaled without pixelation.

If you need complex filtering or want raster graphics instead, a Canvas element and its 2D drawing context are a good choice.