# How to apply borderRadius only for top side of column chart in HighCharts Android wrapper

Tags: android, highcharts, rounded-corners, border-radius

this is not a duplicate question with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316380/how-to-apply-borderradius-only-for-top-side-of-column-or-bar-in-highchart)

For HighCharts **Android wrapper**, if i want to implement below rounded corner only for top side, is there any option for this?

[image]

Same query in github - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/199