# Highcharts: is it possible to set up top border radius for the columns in Column chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, data-visualization, column-chart

I'm trying to set up a column chart that would look like this:

[image: column chart]

And I would like to make top border radius for columns rounded.

I found a solution that looks like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        borderRadius: 8
    }
},
```

However the problem is that the border on bottom part of the columns is getting rounded this way as well:

[image: rounded column chart]

And there's no way to pass a string to that `borderRadius` parameter with a several parameters for each corner., e.g. `borderRadius: '5px 0'`. Is it possible to set it up somehow?

Here's part of documentation that I've been referring to: [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.borderRadius)

NOTE: there's a solution for such problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316380/how-to-apply-borderradius-only-for-top-side-of-column-or-bar-in-highchart) with use of JQuery, however I was wondering whether it is possible to set up in React?

Comment: It seems to be applicable a solution with JQuery, however I was wondering whether it is possible to to implement it in React. Sorry I forgot to mention that in the question @pilchard

Comment: Hi @Konstantink1, This feature requires Highcharts core modification. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vd2Ly9eh/ with the wrapped `translate` method for column series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to modify it by using this plugin [highcharts-border-radius](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-border-radius). In the component with the column chart I added the following import:

```
const borderRadius = require('highcharts-border-radius');
borderRadius(Highcharts);
```

And in the config object that is being passed to HighchartsReact component as `options` prop I added the following:

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            borderRadiusTopLeft: 8,
            borderRadiusTopRight: 8
        }
    },
```

This setup worked for me

Comment: Its good, but what if we have negative values as well, somehow we need to change the borderRadius top and bottom dinamically