# d3js rounded horizontal chart that has a right straight edge at all various levels

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to make a rounded horizontal chart - but there is an issue in the code where the straight edge of the bar is distorting at an incorrect border radius as it gets close to 100%. I also noticed its breaking at low numbers too 1% and 4%.

How do I stabilize the code to ensure the bar chart part is clipped, but never breaks the container

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>multibar d3</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        d3.select("body")
            .selectAll('svg')
            .remove();

        var data = [{"label": "Toblerone", "value": 97}];

        var w = parseInt(280, 10),
            h = parseInt(120, 10);


        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#046395', '#d62828', '#f77f00', '#fcbf49', '#eae2b7']);


        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.total = +d.value;
        });


        var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 20};

        var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleBand()
                  .range([height, 0])
                  .padding(0.1);

        x.domain([0, 100])
        y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.total; }));

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .style('background','#5902f6')
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr('class', 'barchart')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        var border =4;
        var bars = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'bars');
   
      bars.selectAll(".bg")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bg")
      .attr('rx',()=>{
        const barHeight = y.bandwidth();
        return barHeight/2
      })
      .attr('ry',()=>{
        const barHeight = y.bandwidth();
        return barHeight/2
      })
            .attr('fill','#5902f6')
      .attr('stroke','white')
      .attr('stroke-width',border-1)
            .attr("width",x(100))
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth());
      ;
    

     bars.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("fill", "#2cc2d3")
      .attr('stroke','white')
      .attr('stroke-width',3.2)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        const barWidth = x(d.total);
        const barHeight = y.bandwidth();
        const leftCornerRadius = barHeight/2;
        let cornerRadius = barHeight/2;
        if (d.total >= (100 - barHeight/5)) {
            cornerRadius = (d.total - (100 - barHeight/5)) * 2.5;           
            return `
            M ${leftCornerRadius} 0
            H ${barWidth - cornerRadius}
            A ${cornerRadius} ${cornerRadius} 0 0 1 ${barWidth} ${cornerRadius}
            V ${barHeight - cornerRadius}
            A ${cornerRadius} ${cornerRadius} 0 0 1 ${barWidth - cornerRadius} ${barHeight}
            H ${leftCornerRadius}
            A ${leftCornerRadius} ${leftCornerRadius} 0 0 1 0 ${barHeight - leftCornerRadius}
            V ${leftCornerRadius}
            A ${leftCornerRadius} ${leftCornerRadius} 0 0 1 ${leftCornerRadius} 0
            Z
            `;
        } else {
            return `
            M ${cornerRadius} 0
            H ${barWidth}
            V ${barHeight}
            H ${cornerRadius}
            A ${cornerRadius} ${cornerRadius} 0 0 1 0 ${barHeight - cornerRadius}
            V ${cornerRadius}
            A ${cornerRadius} ${cornerRadius} 0 0 1 ${cornerRadius} 0
            Z
            `;
        }
    })

      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return `translate(0, ${y(d.value)})`;
      });


        bars.selectAll(".label")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr('text-anchor', function(d) {
              return d.total <= 20 ? 'start' : 'end';
            })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
              return d.total <= 20 ? x(d.total) + 20 : x(d.total) - 20;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
              return y(d.value) + y.bandwidth() / 2;
            })
            .attr("dy", 5)
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.label;
            });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but then I loose my white container that I am trying to keep in the design

Comment: that still breaks at lower numbers and higher numbers - its the same problem just now without the container there

Comment: Did you have look at the answer for your [post from two weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77205281/d3js-horizontal-chart-with-rounded-hard-edge-boundaries/77270982#77270982) ago?